# Number of trees that can be formed by deleting nodes in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, combinatorics, counting

```
0
|
0__1__0
|  |  |
1__1__0
   |
   1
```

Let's say I have a undirected graph. We have these conditions:

1. You are only allowed to delete nodes labeled as '1'.
2. Deletion of any node must not make the graph a forest

We are allowed to delete multiple nodes, but the above conditions must be satisfied.

Count the number of different trees(unrooted) that can be made by the above process. Note that there is no such thing as 'root' here. We only count the different structures.

For the above, answer is 4 because:

```
0
|
0     0
|     |
1__1__0        ------> #1
   |
   1

0
|
0     0
|     |        -------> #2
1__1__0


0
|
0__1__0
|     |       ---------> #3
1     0

0
|
0__1__0       ---------> #4
      |
      0
```

I would appreciate any kind of help or hints.

(In case the graph is already a tree, we are still allowed to delete nodes to get new trees, subject to the above conditions)

Comment: Is condition 2 the same as "the graph is connected and the result must also be connected"?

Comment: What is a "unrooted tree"? A tree (cyclce-free graph) has always a root, even if we are not interested where it is.

Comment: Yes, that is correct @Codor.

Comment: I wanted to imply that only the structure matters. @deviantfan

Comment: @PrajwalKR I understood that. Btw., generating the result of removed nodes is not hard, and then you want to detect if two graphs are "isomorphic".(NP)

Comment: ...Are you searching a working solution or do you have already something but it´s too slow?

Comment: @deviantfan After we remove the nodes, we should check that the new graph is connected. Why isomorphic here? I know a working solution, which is naive brute force. Remove or don't remove each node marked with 1, and check if the resultant graph is a tree after each removal. But this naive algorithm is exponential.

Comment: Of course you´ll need to check if is connected too. But then you want to count how many structurally different trees are in the result. Isomorphic trees are not structurally different.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am not able to see where I would get that case.

Comment: Can´t do that in the comments. Just think that in your program, you need the nodes with some ID or array index or ... and save where they are connected too. Then, if another tree is theoretically the same but with different IDs... then it´s not easy anymore if you got the same tree multiple times or if they are actually different.

Comment: So, to summarize, the 4 major parts are a) generate subgraphs by removing nodes, b) check if something is connected, c) check if something is cycle-free, d) check if two trees are isomorphic. And multiple things here sounds like NP. I don´t see much potential for speed.

Comment: All I can think of for the above steps you have given is an O(n*2^n) algorithm. I didn't know about the isomorphic problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As you have already pointed out, a naive exponential solution would be to take all subsets of the 1-nodes and for each, checking that removing the nodes gains a tree graph. Two thoughts how you could prune some of the subsets:

1. Build the 1-node subsets incrementally from the smallest to the largest. If you find one that partitions the graph, you don't need to check any of its supersets.

Let me denote the 1-nodes in your example A, B, C, D:

```
0
|
0__A__0
|  |  |
C__B__0
   |
   D
```

Removing `{A, B}` partitions the graph. Therefore obviously removing `{A, B, C}` or `{A, B, D}` or`{A, B, C, D}` also partitions the graph. You don't need to explicitly check any of those.

(Unless all but one of the partitioned graph components consist solely of the 1-nodes. Then removing all these 1-node components could also gain a valid solution. You may need to check this as a special case.)

2. Once you find a 1-node subset that gains a tree; then removing any further 1-node will also gain a tree as long as the graph is not partitioned.

For example, by removing `A` we get a tree:

```
0
|
0     0
|     |
C__B__0
   |
   D
```

We can generate additional trees by removing further nodes. For these we only need to check that by removing them we don't partition the graph. If not, we can be sure the graph remains a tree. Removing `D` in this example illustrates the idea.

These optimizations probably won't make the algorithm better than exponential in the worst case, but they could make it practical for reasonably small input.